# PHP - SOAP Client Unable to Call HTTPS Endpoint

Tags: php, web-services, soap, https, wsdl

I have a problem that I can't call the webservice from other server and it shows error like this :

> **Error Fetching http headers**

When I looked into more detailed error, I realized that the **endpoint** is not right. For example, I wrote this in my php code

```
$client=new SoapClient('https://www.example.com:17819/wsdl/sample.php?wsdl', array("trace" => 1, "connection_timeout" => 5, "exceptions" => 1));
```

The endpoint supposed to be in **https**, but the error shows that the endpoint begins with **http** --> http: //www.example.com:17819/wsdl/sample.php?wsdl

What am I missing in my php client code?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error fetching http headers in SoapClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403486/error-fetching-http-headers-in-soapclient)

Comment: @Mr.Engineer Hi Sir, thanks for your info, But I think My Error is different here. But I Appreciate your info sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this issue. 
I used `nusoap_client` to solve this issue.
And I change the request format too, like this

```
$msg = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:urn='urn:sj_service'>";
```

And so on..

Thanks